# jQuery Datetimepicker XDsoft: How do I get value from inline calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I use the jQuery Datetimepicker plugin from XDSoft: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

I have the calender displayed inline. Here comes my code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="start_date">
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery('#start_date').datetimepicker({
  format:'d.m.Y H:i',
  inline:true
});
```

My problem: When I pick a date in the frontend, the input field does not get the selected date as a value. What changes do I need to make or what do I need to add?

Comment: $('#datetimepicker').val();  
See: https://coding.kz/dev/datetimepicker.html

Answer (score 1):

Get value from `Onchange Event`

Try this

```
onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){
            $('#datePickValue').text($input.val());
        }
```

Full Code look like this

```
jQuery('#start_date').datetimepicker({
  format:'d.m.Y H:i',
  inline:true,
  onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){
    $('#start_date').text($input.val()); // change the div as per your need - change the text as val ( it depends on the field)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [date time picker event](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/).

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="start_date">
```

**JS**

```
var $startDate = $('#start_date');

$startDate.datetimepicker({
  inline:true,
  sideBySide: true
});

$startDate.on('dp.change', function() {
  var selectedDate = $(this).val();
  alert(selectedDate);
});
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1wLht18g/)**

Comment: can i use format as Y-m-d for this plugin. As far as i tried , this format is not working[ its working with Y/m/d and Y.m.d ]

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#start_date').datetimepicker({
  format:"d/m/Y H:i:s",
  inline:true,
  step:5,
  onChangeDateTime:  function (ct,$i) {
    $('#start_date').val(ct.dateFormat('d/m/Y H:i'));
  }
});
```

Try this..It works for me , so it should work for u too..Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

$('#startDate').datetimepicker({ format: 'm-d-Y H:i', minDate: (0), step: 5 }).val();

It's little change working now

Comment: Why would you want to initialise the datetimepicker again just to read the value. Not sure what value this answer adds over the existing answers.